# Build custom target with Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, doxygen

I've a CMake project, with some CMakeLists.txt in subfolders. One of them is:

```
cmake_minimum_required (VERSION 3.7.0)

find_package(Doxygen)

if (DOXYGEN_FOUND)
  configure_file(${CMAKE_CURRENT_SOURCE_DIR}/Doxyfile ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile @ONLY)
  add_custom_target(doc ${DOXYGEN_EXECUTABLE} ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR}/Doxyfile WORKING_DIRECTORY ${CMAKE_CURRENT_BINARY_DIR} COMMENT "Generating API documentation with Doxygen" VERBATIM)
endif(DOXYGEN_FOUND)
```

I can build the project with the usual CMake command for Visual Studio:

```
cmake -G"Visual Studio 12 2013 Win64" ..\myproject\
```

I can build the solution with the following command:

```
cmake --build .
```

But the `doc` custom target defined for Doxygen is not run. How can I run that specific target using the `cmake --build` command?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For build specific target with generic `--build` mechanism use `--target` option:

```
cmake --build . --target doc
```

For completeness, description of other options related with `--build`; taken from [docs](https://cmake.org/cmake/help/v3.0/manual/cmake.1.html):

```
--target <tgt> = Build <tgt> instead of default targets.
--config <cfg> = For multi-configuration tools, choose <cfg>.
--clean-first  = Build target 'clean' first, then build.
                 (To clean only, use --target 'clean'.)
--             = Pass remaining options to the native tool.
```

Comment: And if I want to build it separately? I'd like to have the Visual Studio equivalent of `make doc` for building only documentation.

Comment: `I'd like to have the Visual Studio equivalent of make doc` - then you should build it as `cmake --build . --target=doc`.

Comment: Great! Thanks! Can add this to your reply so I can accept it?

Comment: I have fixed my answer.